# "ubuntu" shows up in boot menu but won't boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 on an Acer mini desktop via CD over an old Debian install from a year ago (which, incidentally, booted without incident).  I blew away windows long ago, no dual-boot, used entire disk. When it finally asked me to remove install media and reboot, all I get is a blank screen with a solid underscore cursor.  I found that if I bring up the F12 menu at boot, it has these options:

```
ubuntu
UEFI: Hitachi HDS7210...
P1: ATAPI DVD A  DH16ABSH
```

If I try to boot off the default, or explicitly through the F12 menu "ubuntu" item, it won't boot -- blank screen, solid underline cursor.

If I boot off the UEFI:Hitachi option, it boots Ubuntu perfectly.

No usb drives, no cd's in the drive, no other hard disks, just the one that Ubuntu's installed on.

Ran Boot-Repair-Disk, my results:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/7277227

Please don't ask me to hit F12 every time...  Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, if I try to boot with my Ubuntu install disk in the CD drive, it boots perfectly into my hard drive -- I know because it comes up with my username login. Also, if I have the Boot-Repair-Disk in the CD drive, it boots into Ubuntu on the hard drive.  I have to select the CD on the F12 menu to get the Boot-Repair-Disk to boot.

Comment: Maybe you should consider repartitioning your hard disk after you boot into a live session with your Ubuntu CD. Leave some space for Windows, you never know when it might come in handy :) . What about this brand new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, don't you want to test it?

Comment: Don't want to be a guinea pig with 14.04.  Don't want Windows.  I'm not playing, here.  I'm installing this to be a server for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your problem. The reason I was telling you to repartition your hard disk was exactly because of some conflicts showed on that Fat32 partition which I suppose is a recovery partition that came together with your laptop.

Comment: Fixed It:  There was a BIOS entry down below the boot priority selection that said "EFI Device Priority".  I selected the "UEFI: Hitachi ..." to be 1st and "ubuntu" to be second and it boots now.

Comment: Floppy, where did you see evidence of a recovery partition?

Comment: By the way, the FAT32 partition that Floppy saw is the UEFI partition (you know -- "extensible firmware" that all the OS wonks are coming in their shorts about).  Thanks, Ubuntu, for getting on the Bleeding Edge so that your distro has maximum probability of not working.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed It: There was a BIOS entry down below the boot priority selection that said "EFI Device Priority". I selected the "UEFI: Hitachi ..." to be 1st and "ubuntu" to be second and it boots now.

Notably, that second boot option (UEFI: Hitachi ...) didn't work the first time I installed Ubuntu.  I had to run the Boot-Recovery-Disk to get that "UEFI: Hitachi ..." boot option to work.

Still don't know what that "ubuntu" entry in the BIOS Setup and F12 menu is, or why it didn't boot on it.